# Top surface scarring even with Z hop

Tags: print-quality

When the print is finished, it looks like the extruder is digging into the top layer as it returns to home?

I tried adding Z hop at 5 mm but it's not really helping.

Sorry for the picture, white on white is hard to show.

I tried a range of speeds from 40-90 mm/s and over extrusion of 100-105 %, but the scar remains.

Any suggestions?

Here is the end code:

```
;TIME_ELAPSED:333.340017
G1 F1500 E417.35346
M140 S0
M141 S0
M107
M104 S0
M140 S0 
;Retract the filament
G92 E1
G1 E-1 F300
G28 X0 Y0
M84
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
M104 S0
```

[image: surface scar 3d print]

[image: z hop settings]

Comment: The gouge you have in the photo would indicate that the nozzle is dropping or the table is raising. Have you observed such movement on completion? Can you make available or otherwise examine the last lines of your G-code for such movement?

Comment: The bed has not lowered at the end of print and the nozzle moves too fast at the end to notice it moved down a tiny bit.  I have added the end of the G-code to the question.

Comment: There are no Z-movements in that portion of the code. Take a look at the lines prior to the termination section to see if you are getting Z-movement in the wrong direction.

Comment: Can you show some more of the gcode leading up to the end G-code you showed? What's the last extruder motion before `G1 F1500 E417.35346`? I wonder if it's making a big glob where the print head ends up then tearing through it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Z-Hops *only occur when the slicer is retracting Filament automatically* (i.e. when Cura detects a move between parts/around outer walls where stringing would be a problem).

In your end G-Code, you *do retract* your filament, but manually. This means that Cura does not add the Z-Hop code.

**Solution:**
Add this before your `G28 X0 Y0` command:

```
G91   ;Change Positioning to relative
G1 Z5 ;Move head up by 5mm (or bed down, depending on your machine)
```

The `G91` command is needed because otherwise you wold need to provide an absolute Z position which is guaranteed to be above your last layer (so you would either need to set the height to the top of your build volume (takes ages to move the head there) or to adjust the height for each printed part (annoying)).

Documentation for the `G91` command: http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G091.html

Manual for Z-Hop and other travel moves in Cura: https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/52507-travel

**Edit:**

Note that this is only a good idea if `MAX_SOFTWARE_ENDSTOPS` are enabled in your Marlin `configuration.h`. Otherwise, the head could move ABOVE the maximum Z height (`zMax`) if the print height `h >= zMax -5mm`.

Thanks to @0scar for mentioning this!

Comment: Note that manual additional Z+ movement should be limited on models that are larger than the maximum Z height minus the additional step/manual Z hop to prevent damage to the printer.

Comment: Good call! And if software endstops are enabled, trying to raise Z above the limit should not be a problem anyways.

Comment: It is best you edit this into your answer though! We can then delete all comments. :-)